# Mongoose create custom _id from other fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I know that Mongoose populates the _id field automatically with an ObjectID if none is given and that you can overwrite the _id when constructing and instance of the model.

What I want: create the _id from other fields in a transparent way. I want to omit the _id field when creating an instance of the model and then have a function called which fills it. This function should be declared on a Schema level and whoever uses the model does not know that _id was filled by the function instead of Mongoose.

Is there a hook or a parameter of the Schema constructor I missed?

Mongoose 3.0.x

**Let's make this more concrete.** Imagine a `BlogPost` and I want to create nice URLs by slugging the title. In order to map the slug to a Mongo Object I hash the slug and turn it into a `ObjectID` to leverage it's benefits. Now what I'm looking for is a transparent method which allows me to create an instance of `BlogPost` by only passing in `title` and have the `slug` and `_id` property automatically generated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use a setter on `title` which slugifies and idifies for you: https://gist.github.com/3658511

If you want to make sure your code is only executed once the object is created, check for `this.isNew` inside the setter.

Comment: I replied on GH as well. It's sounds nice at first, but the setter is called every time, but I only need it once (that's important).

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

You could define a function to create the _id before the model is saved, as in:
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

If this middleware is called after Mongoose creates the _id by default (my guess is it's not), you could tell Mongoose to not create an _id, with the _id option.
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#options

Comment: Well, one problem is the missing documentation for the `init` event (click it on the first of your links)

Comment: You shouldn't need the init event : just use the "pre" middleware.  http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_Schema-pre

Comment: Yes, but where's the docu for pre('init')? Does it fire when the contructor is called or when the Schema is ready or whatever?

Comment: Look under "events" for the link above, although my guess is you can also do what you want with the save event.

Comment: `init` seems inappropriate because I need this for every instance of the model. `save` may be ok, but still not perfect, because it's emitted when the document is updated. I'd need to perform another check to make sure to only do stuff on first save.

Comment: The save check would be very lightweight, since it's happening on the client.

Comment: @Prinzhorn the init method is private which is whats causing that link to not work right. Click the little "private" checkbox at the bottom of the page to see all the private methods. The init method is called internall after a document is returned from the db.